# Number of memory accesses

Tags: assembly, arm

What are the number of accesses of the code:

```
MOV    R1, R0
STR    R4,[R1,#4]!
LDR    R3,[R1]
```

R1-R4 are all 32 bits.

The answer is five and I'm genuinely confused. Can anyone help me with that?
So far I understand MOV does not require memory access, and my guess is two for STR and one for LDR. STR access the memory of R1 and R1+4; while LDR access the memory of R1. But I don't think this is the right explanation, and I don't know which operations account to the addtional 2 memory accesses. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: They're probably counting instruction-fetch: 3 instructions plus a load and a store.  Registers aren't memory.  Some microarchitectures fetch blocks of machine code in wider chunks (and even decode multiple instructions per cycle in parallel), but those uarches would have an I-cache (or a unified L1 cache on older ARMs).  So there'd be 2 data cache accesses (load + store) and one or two I-cache accesses on a high-performance CPU.

Comment: @old_timer: The WB stage in a classic 5-stage RISC is write-back to the *register file* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline).  Which is *a* memory built from SRAM, but it's not *the* "memory" in terms of having a physical memory address and traditionally being outside the CPU core, usually a separate chip.  That's what makes access "to memory" relevant to count, because it normally goes over a bus that might not be full-duplex and which has significant latency.

Comment: Peters answer minus the cache comments is "very likely" how you get to five with this question.  Plus one that or maybe he will post an answer that can be accepted.

Comment: actual, defendable, answers are 2, 5 and 11.  3/5ths of the classic textbook pipeline directly refer to accesses to memories.  And that is important to understand.  The prefetch and cache comment left out massive holes in that the processors fetch multiple instructions with or without the cache enabled.  And if you are trying to count cache accesses you have to talk about mmu, it stables and locations and its table cache, then the tag ram then the cache ram then the prefetch buffer rams all of which are or can be memories but the access count varies and cannot be determined in this context

Comment: (And that the multi instruction prefetches are single bus accesses so could count as a single "access")  prefetch, cache (tag and cache) and other topics later on in the same textbooks thus making the (missing) context here relevant, if we are going to talk about caches and prefetch and register files.